# Custom field type that has multiple fields to extend the default field types

Tags: field, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

Ok scenario that I'd like to create.
Create a custom field type lets call it videos. In this field type you would have 5 separate fields title, description, caption, link, thumb. This would make up the field type which could then be selected from the field type when creating a new field in the CP.

The objective is that this grouped field type could then be re-used within separate matrix fields or as a field in it's own right.

I know you can create field types for plugins but is there a way to create the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you can do this yeah, it just take a little figuring out is all.

Your input template could look something like:

```
<input type="text" name="{{ name }}[title]" value="{{ value.title is defined ? value.title }}">
<input type="text" name="{{ name }}[description]" value="{{ value.description is defined ? value.description }}">
<input type="text" name="{{ name }}[caption]" value="{{ value.caption is defined ? value.caption }}">
<input type="text" name="{{ name }}[thumb]" value="{{ value.thumb is defined ? value.thumb }}">
```

Then in your fieldtypes main class, something like:

```
public function getInputHtml($name, $value)
{

    // If value is null, we set it to an array to prevent template errors
    if(!$value)
    {
      $value = array();
    }

    return craft()->templates->render('bosh/input', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'value' => $value
    ));
}

public function prepValueFromPost($value)
{   
    return json_encode($value);
}

public function prepValue($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, TRUE);
}
```

So basically you are settings the fieldtype value to an array of `pluginHandle[field]` which then you `json_encode` so it can all go into database without any issues.

Then when you retrieve the value from the DB, its a string, so you `json_decode` it into an array. The `TRUE` part states you want an associative array, rather than a `stdClass` object.

Thats pretty much it at a basic level :)

Comment: thanks for the heads up. Thus works to some extent i.e. I get the field type option in the list and can add it to the entry types field layout. However I get an error locating the template file. Unable to find the template “bosh/input“ This sits in the plugin folder under templates/bosh/input.html any ideas?

Comment: yeah sorry bosh is just a silly name I gave to my test plugin. You just need to add the template  (jn your plugin directory) like `templates/input` and then call it like `pluginHandle/input`

Comment: ignore that last comment think I've solved it! Cheers

Comment: getting a slight error on the value fields any clue how to fix it? Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a NULL variable ("")

Comment: Yeah it looks like its because `$value` is null when it gets sent to the template, i've updated the `getInputHtml` method in my answer to show how you could prevent this.

Comment: Cheers @AlexRitson just made a small change to the input fields as it was still throwing an error as the array was empty. All working ok now. One more question if I wanted to add an asset field for the thumb is this possible to create as a field in the plugin template?

Comment: Oh shoot yeah, you should only have needed to add `value.title is defined` on the title call. I assume it is possible, but that might be worth its own question or someone might have posted something? personally i've not tried this.

Comment: @AlexRitson Ok will have a look around. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: @AlecRitson I fixed the edit according to your suggestion, I agree that should resolve the issue. I also removed the `: null`, because [Twig has awesome ternary variations](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators), and doesn't require that part.

Comment: Ah sweet thanks for the edit! I didn't realise twig was that forgiving :)